# PHP 8 Unknown named parameter - Dannyvankooten router

Tags: php, router

Im using this router - https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router, like this:

```
$collection->attachRoute(new PHPRouter\Route('/install.php', [
    '_controller' => 'App\Controllers\Install::Install',
    'methods' => ['GET','POST'],
    'parameters'=> ['template_file'=>'../../install/install'],
]));
```

and i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unknown named parameter $template_file in C:\xampp2\htdocs\vendor\dannyvankooten\php-router\src\Route.php:200
Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\vendor\dannyvankooten\php-router\src\Route.php(200): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\vendor\dannyvankooten\php-router\src\Router.php(143): PHPRouter\Route->dispatch() 
#2 C:\xampp2\htdocs\vendor\dannyvankooten\php-router\src\Router.php(89): PHPRouter\Router->match('/install.php', 'GET')
#3 C:\xampp2\htdocs\core.php(389): PHPRouter\Router->matchCurrentRequest()
#4 {main} 
thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\vendor\dannyvankooten\php-router\src\Route.php on line 200
```

the parameters is added by me, maybe there is the problem... Can you help me ?

On line 389 in core.php i have this:

```
$route = $router->matchCurrentRequest();
```

on route php: https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router/blob/master/src/Route.php
router.php:https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router/blob/master/src/Router.php

Please, give me advice how to fix this problem :)

Answer (score 11):

In php8 you have [named arguments](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments).

https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router/blob/master/src/Route.php#L184
Calls `call_user_func_array`, which accepts the arguments as array.

In php < 8 an associative array was used like a normal indexed array, since the keys hadnt any meaning. In php8 the keys have to match the variable names of your function.

To get your code working you simply have to get rid of the keys:

```
$collection->attachRoute(new PHPRouter\Route('/ajax/dropzone', [
    '_controller' => 'App\Controllers\Ajax\Dropzone::Dropzone',
    'methods' => ['POST','GET'],
    'parameters'=> ['template_file'=>'ajax'],
                    ^---------------^ remove this.
]));
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/DAsGO).

Comment: In this case replace 'template_file' by the name of your first parameter in `Dropzone` and replace `template_file` in `get_object_vars` aswell.